# Exponential with 2 different bases

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

How to solve for the exponent $x$ in $$8^x + 2^{3x} =\frac{1}{4}?$$
Thank you.

Comment: $2^3=8$, so $8^x=2^{3x}.$

Answer (score 3):

Well, we have that:

$$8^x+2^{3x}=\left(2^3\right)^x+\left(2^3\right)^x=2\cdot\left(2^3\right)^x=\frac{1}{4}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\left(2^3\right)^x=\frac{1}{8}=\left(2^3\right)^{-1}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=-1$$

Answer (score 2):

$$8^x+2^{3x}=2^{3x}+2^{3x}=2^{-2}$$
$$2^{3x+1}=2^{-2}$$
$$3x+1=-2$$
$$x=-1$$